# Run procedure in another form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I’m trying to run a procedure in my form ‘frmInvoiceAdd’ from my other form ‘frmDisclosure’. It’s not a Form/SubForm relationship. They are separate. The Procedure in ‘frmInvoiceAdd’ is:

```
CmdInvoice on click:
Public Sub CmdInvoice_Click()
On Error GoTo CmdInvoice_Click_Err

On Error Resume Next
DoCmd.GoToRecord , "", acNewRec
DoCmd.GoToControl "InvDate"
Me.InvDate = Date
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord

DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE tblInvoices SET tblInvoices.DiscFK = [Forms]!
[frmDisclosure]![DiscPK], " & _
             "tblInvoices.ClientFK = [Forms]![frmDisclosure]![ClientFK], 
tblInvoices.ReceiptFK = [Forms]![frmDisclosure]![ReceiptFK] " & _
             "WHERE (((tblInvoices.InvoicePK)=[Forms]![frmInvoiceAdd]!
[InvoicePK])) "

CmdInvoice_Click_Exit:
Exit Sub

CmdInvoice_Click_Err:
MsgBox Error$
Resume CmdInvoice_Click_Exit

End Sub
```

I’m trying to run this from ‘frmDisclosure’ by:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmInvoiceAdd"
Run Forms!frmInvoiceAdd.CmdInvoice_Click
DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmInvoiceAdd"
```

I get this error message:

Microsoft Access can't find the procedure '.'
It highlights:
Run Forms!frmInvoiceAdd.CmdInvoice_Click

I’ve tried changing ‘Run’ to Call but I get this error message:
! Expected: . or (

Answer (score 3):

To call a public sub (or function) in a form module from outside the form module, use this syntax:

```vb
Call Form_NameOfTheForm.NameOfTheSub()
```

in this example:

```
Call Form_frmInvoiceAdd.CmdInvoice_Click()
```

Answer (score 0):

I inserted 
    On Error Resume Next
That solved the problem.

Comment: But does that actually run the procedure? `Call Form_frmInvoiceAdd.CmdInvoice_Click()` should work.

Comment: Yes it ran the procedure but I wasn't happy with having to use On Error Resume Next. I deleted the latter and used your suggestion and it worked. Thank you.